# AngularJS height equalizer hidden div

Tags: angularjs, html, css, css-animations

I am currently trying to build a slider on my page. The slider slides between different content, which means each slider has a different div height. This makes it hard to use animations since I need to use position:absolute; for those (to slide left/right). To work around this, I added a parent container with a position:relative; and used [this directive](https://github.com/pocesar/angular-equalizer) to get equal height on my divs. However, the problem I am facing is that it only gets the height of the first visible div. Meaning it will work fine if the div with the highest height is shown first, but otherwise it won't work (since content will come outside of the slider).

How can I adjust this so that the equalizer gets the height of each div, and gets the one with the highest value in height, and uses that instead of the only visible one?

**Additional info:**
Using ng-show to show the current slide, and css3 animations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty logical. I'm not that great with directives. But after some researching I saw that this directive had a function called equalize() - meaning I could only call EqualizerState.equalize() once I had added EqualizerState to my dependencies.